# How should I configure my JDBC with tnsnames for java web app?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, tnsnames

I don't seem to know what I am doing wrong, I have been stuck for such a long time.

I have this web application which runs on tomcat server. What does is it uses a TNSnames and JDBC to reach an oracle database. I am using odjbc6.jar for this.

1. I have set my odjbc6.jar in the library and buildpath, so that is there.
2. my tnsname is working as intended, I can test it with another program with exaclty the same configuration.
3. I have set my global enviroment

What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need a tnsnames.ora if you are using the thin driver (i.e. the URL starts with `jdbc:oracle:thin`). Show us the JDBC URL you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unfortunatly I need to do it this way. The reason is because this saves me lots of work down the road with the rest of the application. My jdbc url = jdbc:oracle:oci:@mytnsname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that tomcat in eclipse didn't compile everything correctly, but when I exported it to a WAR file and hosted it on a tomcat server then it worked.

It still does not work correctly when I run tomcat on eclipse, which I find strange

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify TNS_ADMIN system var with the complete path to tnsnames.ora file

Comment: I have already done that it points to %ORACLE_HOME$\admin\network

Comment: What version of Oracle is it? usually it is in %ORACLE_HOME$\network\admin  and does tnsping work?

Comment: It is Oracle 12g. Yes it does work when I am using this tnsping with mytnsname. It says ok( msec)

Comment: Do you pass the tnsnames.ora path to the JVM parameters in tomcat? -Doracle.net.tns_admin=<path to tnsnames.ora>

Comment: You can also try to add the property inside the code: System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", System.getenv("ORACLE_HOME") + "\\ADMIN\\NETWORK");

Comment: not specifically. What my program does is: It is bussiness object file which has a datasource. It works fine on the designer application and shows data. But when I use the API on my web app it doesn't connect. I have connected my file before with another way, but without the tnsnames.ora way

Comment: I will try to add it to my connection and see what happens. It might work that way. But it's weird that it would work on the designer application while its exactly  the same datasource.

Comment: I haven't passed it to my JVM parameters in tomcat, i will look into that aswell !

Comment: unfortunately the JVM parameters didn't do the trick. I did point to the file location where the tnsnames.ora is.